# «Употребимый» или «употребляемый»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, морфология, словоизменение

Как бы вы сказали: *наиболее* ***употребимое*** или *наиболее* ***употребляемое*** *слово*? А главное, почему? А как бы вы различали значения этих слов в других контекстах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Из форума: **Слово "употребимые" вообще существует в нормативном русском языке**, например, во фразе "наиболее употребимые слова"? Грамота.ру такого слова не знает. ― Ну, Грамота, может, и не знает, а разные словари очень даже знают.

2)  **А действительно, нормативно ли  слово "употребимый"**?  На Грамоте.ру его нет, в Нацкорпусе тоже нет. Там такая статистика: **употребимый (0)**, **употребляемый (158), употребительный (18)**, **наиболее употребляемый (0)**, самый употребляемый (2), самый употребительный (4), наиболее употребительный (6).

**Примеры:** В целом это достаточно новый, обновляющийся и **довольно употребительный** жаргон (Максим Кронгауз). Это **наиболее употребительный** и добычливый способ рыбной ловли (Н. М. Пржевальский) .На деле же лексический материал, **употребляемый Новиковым**, есть современный эквивалент фольклора (И. А. Бродский). **Самый употребляемый** жир ― топленое свиное сало (из кулинарных рецептов).

3) **Какой можно сделать вывод?** Скорее всего, в языке нормативно существуют **два слова** с разными  оттенками значения: (1) **употребляемый** (от употреблять) и (2) **употребительный**  (употребляемый чаще других, общепринятый).  "Употребительный" может иметь усилительные слова (наиболее, самый), а вот для  слова"употребляемый" их наличие пока еще носит разговорный характер. Но в то же время **ситуация может измениться**, и выражение "самый употребляемый" станет нейтральным, а "наиболее употребительный" перейдет в книжную речь.

Из словаря: **Употребительный**,  такой, который употребляется большинством, многими; общепринятый. Очень у-ое слово. **Малоупотребительный**,  редко употребляемый. М-ое средство. М-ые слова.

4) А теперь вернемся к слову "употребимый", что о нем пишут "в других словарях" [УПОТРЕБИМЫЙ | vedu.ru](http://www.vedu.ru/expdic/121981/)

УПОТРЕБИМЫЙ 1. То же, что употребительный. "Люди без друзей - всё равно что слова, **употребимые вне контекста**"; "Речевые формулы этикета в нормальном обществе являются **общеупотребимыми**". 2. (в значение прилагательное): - в чём? и - для чего? **Приемлемый, пригодный для употребления,** характерный, уместный в данной речевой ситуации, в сочетании с каким-либо понятием, выражением (о слове). - "Ваши канцеляризмы **отнюдь не употребимы** в живой русской речи!"; "К сожалению, эпитеты и метафоры для серых будней повседневности столь **малоупотребимы**...".

Текст довольно сомнительный, а примеры говорят о том, что "употребимый" используется (**или раньше использовался**) в обоих значениях: употребляемый и употребительный.

5)  **Ответ на вопрос:** "Как бы вы сказали: наиболее употребимое или наиболее употребляемое слово"?

**Наиболее употребительное** (книжная и нейтральная речь), **наиболее употребляемое** (разговорная речь). А вот выражение "наиболее употребимое"  мне кажется или неправильным, или архаичным.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Я даже не подумал, что ещё есть третье слово.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе тоже нет? Есть в разных формах. Два вхождения *употребимый* в основном и 89 в газетном корпусе.

Answer (score 2):

(не только о словах)

Наиболее *употребимый* -  самый подходящий, уместный, удобный или пригодный для того, о чём говорят.

Наиболее *употребляемый* - наиболее часто и широко используемый, применяемый на практике.

Answer (score 2):

Однако же, есть устойчивое выражение «широко употребимые слова».  Причем оно встречается в аннотациях и лингвистических пояснениях к словарям, что не позволяет квалифицировать его как лексическую ошибку.

Comment: Пример: Между прочим, те же слова «секс», «эротика», «бисексуальность» и прочие становятся все более широко **употребимыми** и никого уже не вгоняют в краску, а ведь было и по-другому. [Анна БАЛУЕВА. В России вышел западный бестселлер о сексе // Комсомольская правда, 2011.02.22]